# Broken pipe after writing to socket

Tags: c++, c++11, boost-asio

In my network library I can do asynchronous writes to the network if I `run()` and `restart()` the `io_context` manually.

I'm now trying to make things scale by adding a thread pool:

**.hpp**

```
struct pool : public std::enable_shared_from_this<pool> {
  pool(const pool &) = delete;
  auto operator=(const pool &) -> pool & = delete;
  explicit pool(pool_parameters config, db_parameters params) noexcept;

  asio::io_context m_io_context;

  asio::thread_pool m_workers;

  asio::executor_work_guard<asio::io_context::executor_type> m_work_guard;

  /// \brief Container to hold connections.
  std::vector<std::unique_ptr<dbc::connection>> m_connections;
};
```

**.cpp**

```
pool::pool(pool_parameters config, db_parameters params) noexcept
    : m_config{std::move(config)},
      m_params{std::move(params)},
      m_work_guard{asio::make_work_guard(m_io_context)},
      m_workers{m_config.thread_pool_size} {
  m_connections.reserve(m_config.connection_pool_size);
  asio::post(m_workers, [&]() { m_io_context.run(); });
}
```

Which manages connections:

**.hpp**

```
struct abstract_connection : connection {
  explicit abstract_connection(const std::shared_ptr<pool> &pool) noexcept;

  ~abstract_connection() override;
      packet m_buffer;

      asio::local::stream_protocol::endpoint m_endpoint;

      asio::generic::stream_protocol::socket m_socket;

      asio::io_context::strand m_strand;
    };
```

**.cpp**

```
abstract_connection::abstract_connection(const std::shared_ptr<pool> &pool) noexcept
        : m_params{pool->m_params},
          m_config{pool->m_config},
          m_endpoint{pool->m_config.socket},
          m_socket{pool->m_io_context},
          m_strand{pool->m_io_context} {
      m_socket.connect(m_endpoint);
      m_socket.non_blocking(true);
    }

abstract_connection::~abstract_connection() {
      std::error_code ec;
      m_socket.shutdown(asio::generic::stream_protocol::socket::shutdown_both, ec);
      m_socket.close();
    }
```

Now comes the confusing park. On the ctor of a concrete connection object I need to do a handshake, along with a handshake on the destructor of the same class. Which does not happen because the socket object seems to be behaving in odd ways:

If I send data asyncrhonously, nothing gets written to the socket and sometimes I get a broken pipe error:

```
asio::dispatch(m_strand, [&]() {
          m_buffer = write::startup(m_params);
          asio::async_write(m_socket, asio::buffer(m_buffer), [](std::error_code ec, std::size_t len) {});
        });
```

If I do a synchronous write I get a broken pipe error before I can read from the socket:

```
std::error_code ec;
        auto startup = write::startup(m_params);
        asio::write(m_socket, asio::buffer(startup), ec);
        if (set_error(ec)) {
          std::cerr << " XXX " << ec.message() << std::endl;
          return;
        }

        m_buffer.reserve(327);
        asio::read(m_socket, asio::buffer(m_buffer), ec);
        std::cerr << ec.message() << std::endl;
        std::cerr << m_buffer.size() << std::endl;
```

The connection is being done over a unix socket and I have socat sitting between both, so I can see data coming and going, along with the broken pipe messages. Trying to connect to the remote using a third party tool works, with all relevant data appearing in socat, so I believe the problem is in my code.

How can I debug what is going on with the socket?

Comment: It's hard to tell what is going wrong from partial code like this. However, there is a suspicious lack of `->shared_from_this()` in the code you posted, so the issue could very well be badly managed lifetimes. Adding logging code to your ctor/dtor generally helps a lot with tracking these types of errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by making the socket blocking (`non_blocking(false)`) which I would not have thought of without Superlokkus' answer.

Comment: I assume you had to do this because of broken life times, as an real life example I can refer to my project https://github.com/Superlokkus/RTSP/blob/master/src/streaming_lib/rtsp_lib/src/rtsp_server.cpp , but in general I recommend https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rwOv_tw2eA4 i.e. https://github.com/CppCon/CppCon2016/blob/master/Tutorials/Asynchronous%20IO%20with%20Boost.Asio/Asynchronous%20IO%20with%20Boost.Asio%20-%20Michael%20Caisse%20-%20CppCon%202016.pdf

Comment: @Superlokkus non_blocking only affects blocking calls. I added a sleep() to my tests when I use async calls and set the socket to blocking when using sync calls.

Comment: Yes but then your original problem was that your blocking calls would have returned `boost::asio::error::would_block` errors directly on invocation, and the problem was that you did not check for that.

Comment: This is true, I should have checked for that.

Comment: I think however that you also have the problem I mentioned in my answer additionally for the `async_sending`.

Comment: Yes, without the sleep.

Comment: I find it very likely that your sleep is just a more or less broken workaround of your issues. However these are things which can't be solved by a simple SO answer.

Comment: The sleep is in my test, not in the production code.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the code you posted, it seems your `boost::asio::thread_pool` just goes out of scope too early. Your `abstract_connection` class just takes a `const std::shared_ptr<pool> &pool`, which means your abstract connection instances are not holding a reference count on your thread pool. References to `std::shared_ptr` are not making sense in general because of this, let your `abstract_connection` just take a `std::shared_ptr<const pool> pool` in its constructor, which you should copy or move in a member with the same type.

Comment: But the synchronous calls should block the thread until all I/O is done no?

Comment: No it will NOT block, since thread_pool::~thread_pool "Automatically stops and joins the pool, if not explicitly done beforehand.", so your `async_write` will be aborted.